# Error when launching application

Tags: c++, qt, qgis

I have rebuilt the QGIS code on VC2008 on Windows 7.

I have all the correct DLLs in the folder of the exe, and can see that it knows where the QT DLLs are.

When I launch the app, I get this error:

> The procedure entry point ??4QPixmap@@QAEAAV0@$$QAV0@@Z could not be
>   located in the dynamic link library QtGui4.dll

I'm not sure where to start to get this working. I checked the QtGUI4.dll to see that it is loading, with a dummy app. It seems fine.

Any help would be great.

Comment: "I have all the correct DLLs" - why are you sure that you have the correct version of QtGui4.dll in the exe's folder? The error would seem to imply the opposite.

Comment: Make sure the same compiler has built Qt and QGIS. I believe that some distributions of Qt come pre-packaged with a suitable MinGW to build against. You could also set up your own MinGW and compile both Qt and GSIS with it. That should resolve your error.

Comment: @sashoalm - I meant more that, all the references that I used in my make file; I added to the output folder. BUT you are right, QTGui4 might not be the version that is needed.

Comment: See http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Compiling-HelloWorld-and-other-qt-based-examples-vtk-5-10-0-td5715631.html, they have a similar problem, and were linking the wrong Qt version.

Comment: thank you @sashoalm. I had referenced the vs2008 libs in the build, but my system was looking in the vs2010 versions. I have removed all extra versions from my machine. Funny how I gave the path to what version I wanted to use; yet it ignored it. Or the order of load was off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting it as an answer since my hunch turned out correct:

This error shows that your application was loading the wrong Qt DLLs. For whatever reason, it was finding and loading DLLs different from the DLLs against which it was built. In your case it turned out it was finding Qt4 built for VS2010 DLLs, while it needed Qt4 built for VS2008.

The solution is to make sure it always finds the correct DLLs - place the correct DLLs in the EXE's folder, as this is usually the first place it looks for for DLLs. On Windows, it's not a good idea to rely on `%PATH%` or on the current directory.